# Split brain scenario - RAC and PXC

Tags: mysql, oracle, percona, xtradb-cluster, oracle-rac

Even though split brain scenario occurs in both Oracle RAC and Percona's XtraDB Cluster, a two node cluster is allowed and split brain scenario is resolved in RAC but a two node is not recommended in Percona Cluster ( 3 nodes is recommended ). Why is it like that? Doesn't Percona resolve split brain happening in two node cluster? I know I'm comparing two different technologies.. but still if anyone could clear this out.

Thanks!

Comment: You actually answer many questions but you do not upvote the ones which interests you.. Kidding :)  will do it henceforth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why Oracle RAC can handle split brain and PXC cannot.

What separates them in their architecture and data storage. In what ways ???

## Oracle RAC

- All RAC Instances deal with only one set of database files
- Each RAC Instance has its own Log Buffer and LGWR (Log Writer) process
- Writes to any Oracle RAC instance, even on nodes that go down temporarily, can have their log sequence numbers coalesced and serialized

## Percona XtraDB Cluster

- Each PXC node has its own complete set of data
- Writes to one PXC node must be rolled back or committed on all nodes in unison
- Writes to PXC nodes that are split in communication will only update/commit to its local copy of the data. Awareness of such writes by other unconnected PXC nodes does not exist when communication has been established again.

According to [**Percona's Frequently Asked Questions on PXC**](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/faq.html#q-how-would-it-handle-split-brain)

> Q: How would it handle split brain?
>
> A: It would not handle it. The split brain is hard stop, XtraDB Cluster can’t resolve it. That’s why the minimal recommendation is to have 3 nodes. However there is possibility to allow a node to handle the traffic, option is:
>
> ```
> wsrep_provider_options="pc.ignore_sb = yes"
> ```

## SUMMARY

- Oracle RAC is ACID compliant as a Cluster (again, one set of database files)
- Percona XtraDB Cluster abides by [CAP Theorm instead of ACID compliance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31260/consistency-in-acid-and-cap-theorem-are-they-the-same/31261#31261)
- See YouTube video where Vadim Tkachenko (Percona CTO) discusses the split-brain scenario and how it is your responsibility ([Video starts from 17:00 mark, listen up to 19:20 or more](https://youtu.be/VCvTgA2mYnE?t=17m00s))

Comment: so split brain in PXC can be overcome if I use 3 nodes instead of 2 nodes?

Comment: @tesla747 - Yes.  At least 3 nodes gives a "split" situation a quorum wherein the majority decides that it is still the "true" cluster, and the minority understands that it is no longer a valid part of the cluster.  Upon reconnection, the nodes will converse, and the minority will be updated with changes that happened during the split.

Comment: For true HA, the 3 nodes should be in 3 geographically dispersed data centers.  (Think, flood, earthquake, tornado, etc.)